# How can I feed a batch into LSTM without reordering them by length in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I am new to Pytorch and I have got into some trouble.
I want to build a rank-model to judge the similarity of question and its answers (including right answers and wrong answers). And I use LSTM as an encoder.

There are two LSTMs in my model and they share the weights. So my model’s input is two sequences (question and answer). But if I use batch, reordering will disrupt the correspondence between questions and answers.
What should I do?

Comment: who told you to reorder? and why you need reordering? if you want to shuffle, you can put the sequences (both questions and answers) in a list and the do the shuffling, you won't lose the correspondence in that case.

Comment: This is because I want to use  [pack_padded_sequence](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html?highlight=lstm#torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence)  to pack the data. This function ask us to reorder the sequence by length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a starting point could be to use similar RNN wrapper as here https://github.com/facebookresearch/DrQA/blob/master/drqa/reader/layers.py#L20 
You can encode question and asnwer separately (this module will pack and unpack internally and will take care of sorting) and then you can work on the encoded representations

Comment: I soved this problem by your advice. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded some useful torch utilities for NLP. Some might be useful for pack_padded_sequence: https://github.com/wjpjet/torch_utilities/blob/master/torch_util.py